# Superset API Request Filters

Tags: apache-superset

I'm attempting to retreive a list of dashboards via the superset API which have a specific owner.  I've attempted many unsuccessful ways to compose the request:

```
/api/v1/dashboard/?q={
  "filters": [
    {
      "col": "owners__username",
      "opr": "eq",
      "value": "bi"
    }
  ]
}
```

Resulted in `Filter column: owners__username not allowed to filter`

```
/api/v1/dashboard/?q={
  "filters": [
    {
      "col": "owners",
      "opr": "any",
      "value": {
          "col": "username",
          "opr": "eq",
          "value": "bi"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Result: `Not a valid rison schema`

```
/api/v1/dashboard/?q={
  "filters": [
    {
      "col": "owners",
      "opr": "any",
      "value": "ADMIN0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which gives me all results

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`/api/v1/dashboard/?q=(filters:!((col:owners,opr:rel_m_m,value:4)))`

So that filter only accepts user id's

You can get a list of supported filters on each resource by:

`/api/v1/dashboard/_info?q=(keys:!(filters))`

Comment: Note that the `q` parameter must be formatted as Rison (https://github.com/Nanonid/rison), not JSON. Rison is a compact form of JSON designed for URLs.